# 特定のメール（独自ドメイン）だけが受信できない

Tags: mail

送信側（特定アドレスxxx@example.com）から特定アドレス（独自ドメインxxx@example.co.jp）のメールへ送信処理をしても、メールが届かない。
これらの受信側、送信側も、他（上記のドメイン以外）の独自ドメインのメールアドレスに関しては送受信できています。
逆に、届かなかった受信者から、送信者へのメールは送信でき、メールが受信者に届きます。
ログ等の内容としては
届かなかった受信側サーバーログ等を確認しましたが、送信側から送信されたログの確認ができない。
受信側のメールボックスにも受信されず入らない。
送信側のメールクライアントソフト内では、送信済みフォルダーに送られて、送信されているという判断。
送信側のSMTPのログ等がまだ確認できていない。
この状況は、どのような時におこりえるというものなのでしょうか？
もし、仮にSMTPからの送信ログがあった場合、受信側のメールサーバーまで到達できない状況の理由としては何があるか？
SMTPからの送信が行われていなかった場合、メールクライアントソフト上の設定が原因なのか、ポートなど？

Comment: 送信側メールサーバのログが必要です。

Comment: メールの送信受信の不備については、様々な原因が発生します。送信受信クライアント側の問題であったり、送信受信サーバの設定の不備であったり、いくつもの原因が重なって起きることもあります。いただいた情報だけですと経験による推測による回答しかできず、なかなか的を射たものを得ずらい印象です。コメントにもありますがまずはログによる正確な現象の把握が遠回りのようで最短の手順です。

Comment: 「独自ドメイン」とは何ですか?

Comment: 特定の独自ドメインのメールアドレス

Comment: 独自ドメインはドメイン登録サービスで取得できるオリジナルドメインのこと

Comment: 送信側のログがわからない状況、送信側の管理者によれば、送信したログを確認したとのこと、このことが正しければ、なぜ受信サーバーまでたどり着けないのか？です

Comment: 送信側が確認したとのことですが、受信サーバにログが残っていない以上、それも怪しいです。正しい受信サーバのIPに送信していますか？受信側も送信ログの日時をあわせてログは本当に残ってないですか？